# How to show ForeignKey obj name on add data admin mode

Tags: python, django, web

How to show detail about foreignkey

link pic : https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2019/08/05/KLGvi9.png

and my code in below.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class Anniversary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    anniversary = models.ForeignKey(Anniversary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(
    Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in your Anniversary model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.date)
```

This will show date in the anniversary drop-down.

Comment: As per *stack overflow* if this solves your issue. Mark it as *accepted answer*.